# PyObjC: How can one use NSCoding to implement python pickling?

Tags: python, pickle, nscoding, pyobjc

Title says it all. It seems like it ought be possible (somehow) to implement python-side pickling for PyObjC objects whose Objective-C classes implement `NSCoding` without re-implementing everything from scratch. That said, while value-semantic members would probably be straightforward, by-reference object graphs and conditional coding might be tricky. How might you get the two sides to "collaborate" on the object graph parts?

Answer (score 1):

PyObjC does support writing Python objects to a (keyed) archive (that is, any object that can be pickled implements NSCoding).

That’s probably the easiest way to serialize arbitrary graphs of Python and Objective-C objects.

As I wrote in the comments for another answer I ran into problems when trying to find a way to implement pickle support for any object that implements NSCoding due to incompatibilities in how NSArchiver and pickle traverse the object graph (IIRC primarily when restoring the archive).

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be pretty straightforward?

On pickling, call `encodeWithCoder` on the object using an `NSArchiver` or something. Have pickle store that string.

On unpickling, use `NSUnarchiver` to create an `NSObject` from the pickled string.

Comment: That doesn’t work for object graphs that have references from ObjC objects back to Python objects.

Comment: I sadly enough forgot to document the issues I ran into when I tried to implement support for pickling arbitrary ObjC objects that support the NSCoding protocol.  IIRC the problem is related to the way pickle and NSCoding traverse the object graph. It was fairly easy to add NSCoding support for any Python object that can be pickled, but not the other way around.

Comment: If anyone does find a way to pickle objects implementing the NScoding protocol: please let me know on PyObjC’s issue tracker as I’d love to have support for this in PyObjC itself.