# Swift Serialize a Sparse Matrix Generated using Python

Tags: python, swift, serialization

I have some python code that I use to generate a `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`.

I need to use this matrix in an App, using Swift.

I've found that I can use Accelerate to store a sparse matrix. Using [these docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/creating_sparse_matrices) I wrote an algorithm in Python that builds the required `rowIndices`, `columnStarts` and `values` necessary to create a `SparseMatrixStructure`, and hence build a `SparseMatrix_Float`.

However, to import these values into the app, I'm using a JSON. The JSON is quite large, and would benefit from being converted into binary.

At this point I would usually turn to `protobufs`. However, the App Maintainer has a policy of not using Cocoapods or other external libraries.

Is there an efficient way of serializing this data in Python (where I'm free to include any library), and deserialize the data in swift (using only standard tools)?

Comment: There is a library PyObjC https://pypi.org/project/pyobjc/ which is a bridge between python and objective-c, you can use it to archive your matrix using NSCoding (this is a conversation about this topic 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21730339/pyobjc-how-can-one-use-nscoding-to-implement-python-pickling?rq=1 ). `NSCoding` is natively handled by swift / iOS, you don't need any external library.

Comment: Thanks, I think this could be a really helpful suggestion. I'm struggling to get a good example of what I'm aiming at. Please could you give a minimal example of how I would use it?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a compromise solution.

1. Write the big JSON file to disk using Python.
2. Use a Swift playground to run the parsing code to convert the JSON into `Codable` structs.
3. Using the same playground convert the struct to `Data` using a `PropertyListEncoder`.
4. Save the `Data` and include in the app.
5. Read the data into structs in the app using a `PropertyListDecoder`.